# Cannot uninstall old version of gem from macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, macos-catalina

On macOS Catalina 10.15.1, I have a few Ruby gems where two versions are installed, one under each of the following two directories:

Older:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
```

Newer:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems
```

I would like to uninstall the older versions from under `/System/…`, but, when I run the following commands, I get the associated errors:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall CFPropertyList --version 2.3.6
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    CFPropertyList is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 CFPropertyList

$ sudo gem uninstall -i /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 CFPropertyList
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

I also get the same error if I run the last command without `sudo`.

How can I remove the old versions of the gems?

On a related note, I have a few gems that are only under the `/System/…` directory, not the `/Library/…` directory.  How can I move them from the former to the latter?

Comment: I would use rvm with gemset and bundler.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: I don’t code in Ruby, I’m just trying to keep all components on my system up-to-date, mainly for security & bug fixes. I’ve never intentionally installed extra gems, I’ve only updated what was pre-installed on my Mac. (Maybe a gem was installed when I installed some software to use). If I can easily get rid of all existing gems and use something like churby, that could work, but I don’t want to leave old gems on my file system.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a version manager and don't worry at all about system ruby / gems?  You can for example try RVM.  See [install instructions here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

Or Churby see https://github.com/postmodern/chruby

UPDATED:  Don't mess with system libraries that were installed by your OS. They are likely there for a good reason.  If you don't know what you're doing, you might break something somewhere.  For system and security updates, stick to the OS system updates and patches as they release them.

Comment: I don’t code in Ruby, I’m just trying to keep all components on my system up-to-date, mainly for security & bug fixes. I’ve never intentionally installed extra gems, I’ve only updated what was pre-installed on my Mac. (Maybe a gem was installed when I installed some software to use). If I can easily get rid of all existing gems and use something like churby, that could work, but I don’t want to leave old gems on my file system.

Comment: @XDR If the system has installed them, there's probably a good reason and you shouldn't need to worry about managing them yourself. See updated anser.